# Why isn't my variable being recognized after calling Math.ceil on a value?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I apologize if the true problem is not reflected in the title; I'm unsure exactly where the issue lies here. I have a variable, 'text' that is set to the value of 'score' rounded to the nearest percentage using Math.ceil.

I should be able to output 'text' as a property of an event in my Mixpanel code. However, I find that the event will not show up in Mixpanel at all when I use the variable 'text.'  It will, however, output 'score'--as a crazy percentage, because score has not been rounded unless 'text' is used as the variable.  I'd appreciate some eyes on this; is there some reason 'text' cannot be referenced?  Why shouldn't Mixpanel be able to output this event if I assign text to a property?

```
browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({
      text: score ? `${Math.ceil(score)}%`: "",
      tabId

    }),
    browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(tabs => {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];


     Mixpanel.track("Button icon fired", { "Compatibility Score": text+"%", "Current URL":activeTab.url})
    })
  ]);
```

Comment: There's is no variable called `text` anywhere in your code until you're referencing it near the end. What you have near the start is an object literal with a `text` key, but that doesn't set any variable. You'll probably want to do `const text = Math.ceil(score);` then use that in both the places you have in your code.

Comment: Hey, thanks Chris G!  That solved my issue! I understand now about how text wasn't a variable the way it was set up, and will keep this in mind from now on. Very grateful for your assistance:) If you want to copy your comment into an answer, I will mark it as correct.